# How long will modern society remain in the archaeological record?

Tags: science-based, magic, science-fiction, fantasy-races, low-fantasy

I have an extreme far future setting (we're talking hundreds of thousands, if not millions of years) wherein humanity has speciated and reverted to a cultural and technological level very similar to the middle ages. (Read: Generic high fantasy)

So, I was wondering what sorts of cool artefacts people might be likely to find.

Bonus: How far in the future would my setting realistically be, assuming humanity has had the time to become the various races that we see in stereotypical high fantasy, and split off into at least two species?

Comment: If you are open to the possibility of bio engineering developing reasonably well in the next couple of decades, you can do the two species thing pretty soon. Before you ask about the remains, perhaps first decide how long those artifacts have to survive. A thousand or a million years - that's very, very different

Comment: You should ask the bonus question in a separate post and delete it here. Better to have one question or one *closely linked* set per post.

Comment: We have found glass artefacts four thousand years old... And glass was rare then. Our abundance of glass objects will produce "cool artefacts" for tens of thousands of years. Our ceramic tiles will also last for a very very long time. Our high-voltage power grid will generate very long mysterious ley lines of deposits of metallic oxides. Our massive earthworks will be recognizable for hundreds of thousands of years. Our cyclopean gravity dams will also remain recognizable for a very long time. We also have immense amounts of gold jewelry...

Comment: Here is a [list](https://www.keepcasscountybeautiful.com/images/PDF/Recycling/how_long_does_it_take_garbage_to_decompose.pdf) of how long it takes for some things to decompose. You can search for other items specifically.

Comment: ever heard of anthropocene ? even geologists will find record of modern society

Answer (score 5):

**Recognizably artificial artifacts? Several hundred million years.**

People are digging up dinosaur bones. Every now and then, the fossils have impressions of wings, feathers, etc. Now imagine digging up human fossils with wristwatches, gold teeth, pacemakers, artificial hip joints.

For that matter, ceramics like toilet bowls should make an interesting impression if they are buried in what becomes sandstone. Nuclear waste sites start as poison and become "interesting" isotope ratios.

Of course that assumes analysis on a present-day technological level. Something a medieval "natural philosopher" would recognize is more difficult.

Comment: Humans rarely die in fossilisable situations these days. We tend to be cremated, or buried in cemeteries.

Comment: @ArkensteinXII, there are quite a lot of us. A small fraction would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

**Stainless Steel** is very resistant to corrosion, even when exposed to acid, bases, and organic solvents. Different grades of stainless steel have different degrees of resistance. According to [this article](https://www.bssa.org.uk/topics.php?article=51), it takes 1200 years to corrode 1 mm of stainless steel of type 316(1.4401) in rural conditions. A 10 cm rod or plate of this sort of stainless steel would hence take 120,000 years to corrode.

While **plastics** are a huge waste problem today, most plastics will degrade in a few hundred years. According to [this article](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2018/01/10/stark-truth-long-plastic-footprint-will-last-planet/), plastic bottles, nappies, and six-pack beer holders take 450 years to degrade, while fishing line takes 600 years. It is hence not by our plastic waste that far-future civilizations will recognize us, though I can't rule out that some less-common types of plastics take far longer to decompose.

**Glass**, on the other hand, lasts quite a long time. A glass bottle, for instance, lasts a million years in 'the environment', according to [this source](https://www.keepcasscountybeautiful.com/images/PDF/Recycling/how_long_does_it_take_garbage_to_decompose.pdf); far longer than other types of common waste. Even aluminum cans don't last longer than 80-200 years.

**Radioactive waste** is also around for a long time. The most common elements in [radioactive waste](https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/fact-sheets/radwaste.html), strontium-90 and cesium-137, have half-lives of only about 30 years and will hence cease to be noticeably radioactive in a few hundred years. Plutonium-239, on the other hand, has a half-life of 24,000 year and can hence be detected hundreds of thousands of years into the future. However, there will probably be very little of this, since plutonium and uranium in radioactive waste is typically separated to be used as fuel.

We should not rule out something as old-fashioned as **stone**. Cut stone has been a common building material throughout human history and is still extensively used. Stone doesn't corrode much, though e.g. marble may corrode somewhat with long exposure to acid rain. Large structures of stone, or the remains thereof, should be recognizable for hundreds of thousands of years. especially if buried in sand or earth.

In conclusion, some remains of our current civilization will be recognizable at least a few hundred thousand years from now, with glass lasting much longer. This should be enough for human beings to evolve into different species, particularly if small populations live far apart under extreme conditions that promote evolution and adaptation. [Homo Sapiens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_sapiens) is thought to have split from Neanderthals somewhere between 260,000 and 500,000 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this recent Atlantic essay, which basically answers your question (and the answer is pretty dismal): https://amp.theatlantic.com/amp/article/595795/

tl;dr Given millions of years, our entire society, skyscrapers and all, could be reduced to a thin, centimeter-thick seam in the geological strata, because even steel structures will eventually be pulverized by the awesome power of tectonic plate subduction. Our most noticeable imprint, sadly, will be all of the carbon dioxide that we’re dumping into the atmosphere right now. Nuclear waste will also last a while.

And yes, sure, there will be some fossils, but as with any fossils, there won’t be many, especially because we bury ourselves in wooden boxes and not in muddy river beds and bogs.

Humans likely won’t be around in millions of years, though. We’ll probably render ourselves extinct before then if an asteroid or supervolcano doesn’t first. Thousands of years sounds like a more plausible timeframe for your story. I’m reminded of the disturbing novel Ridley Walker, in which society has reverted to Iron Age technology a few thousand years after a nuclear apocalypse. In that scenario, machinery from before the fall is still around, but nobody knows what it’s for, which is really eerie and sad.